# How to change color of TemplateField

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I would like to know how to change the background color of a templateField with CSS. I tried to set it in the HTML Page like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label` BackgroundColor="White">
```

But is doesn't work when I do a mouseover, because the BackgroundColor would stay the same....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want like below

[image]

Then change to

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BackColor="LightGreen">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is because of the databound the field stays the same color, so when I'm doing a mouseover the background of the label or textbox is still white or gray or whatever

Answer (score 0):

A TemplateField is nothing more than a `<tr>` in html. So you can apply a CSS class to it, either directly

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="class">
//or
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BackColor="White">
```

Or with inheritance in CSS

```
<style>
    #<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```

**Update**

To get what you describe, use a pure CSS solution by assigning a class to the GridView and the Label

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewClass">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="class" ItemStyle-BackColor="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="GridViewLabel"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<style>
    .GridViewClass tr {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .GridViewLabel {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .GridViewClass tr:hover, .GridViewClass tr:hover .GridViewLabel {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is because of the databound the field stays the same color, so when I'm doing a mouseover the background of the label or textbox is still white or gray or whatever

Comment: Updated my answer.